# Solving a system of differential equations, and periodicity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**The question**

Given the following system of differential equations

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\; \dot{x} & = & y-1 \\ 
\; \dot{y} & = & -xy
\end{matrix}\right.$

Give a differential equation for its trajectories and solve it. Find which trajectories are closed, and therefore correspond to periodical solutions.

**My problem**

I know that it follows from the chain rule that

$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \; \Rightarrow \; \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}$

so that after substituting in the equations from the above system a trajectory is given by the planar coordinates $x(t), \; y(x(t))$ for $y$ a solution to the differential equation

$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{-xy}{y-1}$

When I try to solve this as a seperable differential equation however, I end up with a nasty solution from which I cannot isolate $y$. Furthermore I have no idea how to determine if a trajectory is closed, or how to show any solution is periodical. What should my approach be?

Comment: I feel like any trajectory for this system is going to be periodic. First of all, I don't think you need to find the solution for this system. I just draw a phase portrait about the steady state (0,1). If you can find a bound for any solution, then since the steady state is unstable, the solution must be periodic.

Comment: @TinPhan This could show the existence of at least one periodic solution, not that all solutions (in the upper half plane, as it happens) are periodic.

Answer (score 1):

The line $y=0$ is invariant (from the differential equation). Hence, there are no periodic orbits in the region $y<0$ since this is invariant and since $x'<0$ for $y<0$ (in a periodic orbit each component of the vector field changes sign somewhere).

For $y>0$ notice that 
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac12x^2+y-\log y\right)=xx'+y'-\dfrac{y'}{y}=0.$$
Hence, each orbit is on a level set of the function $\frac12x^2+y-\log y$. Each level set is in fact a closed curve (without intersections) and so all orbits in the region $y>0$ other than the equilibrium point are periodic.

Comment: I understand you up until your conclusion - along the curve of every solution, the function $\frac{1}{2}x^{2} + y - \log(y) = c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. But from what does it follow that these level sets are closed curves, and how is it possible to conclude that all specified orbits are periodic?

Comment: Well, the rest is up to you. There is no general method, although my favorite is to think of it as energy conservation, it all depends on what you know.